# Sequelize/Node – Concat to null value

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to concat the number '2' to a value in a row that at times may be `null`. Other times, it will be a string. I'm using the Sequelize.fn method to concat the '2', but in the cases where the value is null, it does not do anything. Specifically, it remains null and does not become '2' as I would expect. If the value isn't null, but rather a string, it works. I have confirmed this by checking the resulting values in the database itself. Is there another way to concat to a null value with Sequelize?

Here's the code that attempts to concat to null, simplified:

```
mysql.determineDatabase('db-name', 'table-name').then((database) => {
  database.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
    database.table_name.update({
      code: Sequelize.fn('concat', Sequelize.col('code'), 2)
    }, { where: { code: req.body.code }
    }).then((result) => {
      res.status(200).send({ ... });
    }).catch((error) => {
      res.status(400).send(error);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anybody stumbles upon this question and needs an answer, I ended up doing this instead of trying to use sql functions:

```
mysql.determineDatabase('db-name', 'table-name').then((database) => {
  database.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
    database.table_name.findAll({ where: { code: req.body.code } })
      .then((response) => {
        const code = response[0].dataValues.code;
        const concatenatedCode = code === null ? 2 : `${code}2`;
        database.table_name.update({
          code: concatenatedCode
        }, { where: { code: req.body.code }
        }).then((result) => {
          res.status(200).send({ ... });
        }).catch((error) => {
          res.status(400).send(error);
        });
      });
  });
});
```

Basically, I'm just getting the previous value through `.findAll()`. If the returned value is `null`, I replace it with 2, otherwise, I concat 2.